# Why will this function not end its loop even when the conditions have been met?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, time

I have created this script to open a website at a certain time of the day, but when I try to create a loop for it to check until the conditions have been met, (in this case the conditions are that the time is 13:27), the website does not open even when it is the correct time, but the program is still running in IDLE.

```
import datetime
import webbrowser
x = datetime.datetime.now()
def website():
    if (x.hour) == 13:
        if (x.minute) == 27:
            webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/", new = 2)
        else:
            sleep(10)
            website()
    else:
        website()
```

EDIT: Along with not initialising x more than once I realised that I haven't actually called the function oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable x is only initialized once, and is not updated when the function is recalled.

```
import datetime
import webbrowser
def website():
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    if (x.hour) == 13:
        if (x.minute) == 27:
            webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/", new = 2)
        else:
            sleep(10)
            website()
    else:
        website()
```